# LEN-Function works different by same text

Tags: sql, string-length

i have a Table with column nvarchar(50) and i want to select the length of the text.

the results are very different:

[image]

The first valid DMC is 34 long, the second valid is 36 long also the third and the fourth valid DMC is 32 long. The results are others, 38, 40, 36 and 32.
for failstop there are also different results, 38 and 8.

If i try it without a table it works correctly. as example:

```
declare @DMC as nvarchar(50);
set @DMC = 'failstop'
select LEN(RTRIM(REPLACE(@DMC, CHAR(32), ''))) as Result
```

Result = 8

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What query you are using on the table ?

Comment: See what the *35th* character is; `select top 1 unicode(substring(DMC, 35, 1))`

Comment: What query are you performing on the table?

Comment: In SQL Server LEN does not count trailing spaces, it does count other hidden characters though, i.e. TAB, CR, LF etc. I think this is what @AlexK. is getting at.

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: If you are ever in doubt about what a character column really contains, try `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), column)` and `SELECT DATALENGTH(column)`, that should clear things up. SSMS is bad at displaying whitespace and nonprintable characters.

Comment: on the table i use the same query!

Comment: i have detected the problem. there are many unicode = 0 "characters" in the DMC strings. but i dont know how to clear the 0-values. the replace-statement dont work --> REPLACE(DMC, UNICODE(0), '')

Comment: Try `REPLACE(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), DMC), 0x0000, 0x)`. You can't select or replace NUL characters, but you can do the same for `0`-bytes.

Comment: it works with: LEN(RTRIM(REPLACE(CAST(DMC-Column AS varchar(MAX)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, CHAR(0), '')))